# DataSnap did not close SQL Server Connection's

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I have DataSnap Server with connection to MS SQL Server database. I use Zeos Connection objects. Client is Android application. Both are made in Delphi XE10.2. When my android client lost connection to DataSnap Server connection to MS SQL Server remains still active and never close. If I gracefully closes Android client application it does not happen. After some disconnections I get message db error 10029 - Maximum number of DBPROCESSes already allocated and I must restart my DataSnap server. What should I do.

DataSnap server application looks like this.

ServerContainer Unit Form :

```
object ServerContainer1: TServerContainer1
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Height = 271
  Width = 415
  object DSServer1: TDSServer
    Left = 96
    Top = 11
  end
  object DSTCPServerTransport1: TDSTCPServerTransport
    PoolSize = 100
    Server = DSServer1
    Filters = <>
    Left = 96
    Top = 73
  end
  object DSServerClass1: TDSServerClass
    OnGetClass = DSServerClass1GetClass
    Server = DSServer1
    Left = 200
    Top = 19
  end
end
```

Code :

```
unit ServerContainerUnit1;

interface

uses System.SysUtils, System.Classes,
  Datasnap.DSTCPServerTransport,
  Datasnap.DSServer, Datasnap.DSCommonServer,
  IPPeerServer, IPPeerAPI, Datasnap.DSAuth;

type
  TServerContainer1 = class(TDataModule)
    DSServer1: TDSServer;
    DSTCPServerTransport1: TDSTCPServerTransport;
    DSServerClass1: TDSServerClass;
    procedure DSServerClass1GetClass(DSServerClass: TDSServerClass;
      var PersistentClass: TPersistentClass);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
  end;

var
  ServerContainer1: TServerContainer1;

implementation


{$R *.dfm}

uses
  ServerMethodsUnit1, main;

procedure TServerContainer1.DSServerClass1GetClass(
  DSServerClass: TDSServerClass; var PersistentClass: TPersistentClass);
begin
  PersistentClass := ServerMethodsUnit1.TServerMethods1;
end;

end.
```

Server Methods Unit looks like this :

[Print screen of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a69mI.png)

There is no code except EchoString and ReverseString function in this unit

On the client side I have DataModule with TSQLConnection, TDSProviderConnection and many TClientDataSets

One of procedure's in my client app looks like this :

```
procedure A();
begin
  try
    DM.PingCDS.Close;
    DM.PingCDS.Open;
  except
    DM.Konekcija.Close;
    DM.Konekcija.Open;
  end;
  DM.KorisnikCDS.Close;
  DM.KorisnikCDS.Params.ParamByName('aplikacija').Value := 'S';
  DM.KorisnikCDS.Open;
  while not DM.KorisnikCDS.Eof do
  begin
    i := DM.KorisnikCDS.RecNo;
    k := TKorisnik.Create;
    k.user_name := DM.KorisnikCDSUSER_NAME.AsString;
    k.pass := 'd' + inttostr(i);
    k.IDKorisnik := DM.KorisnikCDSID_KORISNIK.AsInteger;
    k.ImeIPrezime := DM.KorisnikCDSIME.AsString + ' ' + DM.KorisnikCDSPREZIME.AsString;
    k.frame := TframeKorisnik.Create(hbKorisnici);
    k.frame.Parent := hbKorisnici;
    k.frame.Korisnik := k;
    k.frame.Position.X := 10 + (i - 1) * k.frame.Width;
    k.frame.Position.Y := 0;
    k.frame.Name := 'frameKorisnik' + IntToStr(k.IDKorisnik);
    k.frame.lblUserName.Text := k.user_name;
    k.frame.Opacity := 0.7;
    ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
    (DM.KorisnikCDSSLIKA as TBlobField).SaveToStream(ms);
    ms.Position := 0;
    k.frame.imgKorisnik.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(ms);
    ms.Free;
    k.frame.OnTap := TapKorisnik;
    //k.frame.OnMouseUp := KornisnikMouseUP;
    ListaKorisnika.Add(k);
    DM.KorisnikCDS.Next;
  end;
  DM.KorisnikCDS.Close;
end;
```

You can see that I created Ping query to determine is Connection to DataSnap Server still alive. If not I reconnect. I think that is the problem. If connection to DataSnap server broke, SQL connection still stay active and when I reconnect to DataSnap server I see new SQL Connection in Activity monitor. Old one never disconnect

This is print screen of Activity monitor with few connections that never ends.

[Print screen of Activity monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZUg2.png)

I hope any one of you can help me

Comment: "What should I do."  Provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that is, the code of a minimal example server and cliet which exhibit the problem.

Comment: Alternatively to what @MartynA suggested, you could try googling for the same or similar questions already asked. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202650/2292722 . Suggested search phrase: *datasnap server detect disconnected client*

Comment: Sorry both of you. I edited my post and hope you can help me

Comment: In my view there's nothing you can do about it, and why do you care so much anyway?

Comment: Some time I get message : maximum number of dbprocesses already allocated
and I must restart my DataSnap service

Comment: Is this a Zeos error message?

Comment: I thik it is Zeos error